# A generic cron wrapper that records all output

Tags: shell, cron, zsh, io-redirection

I am hoping to write a cron wrapper that records all output in a folder `$CRON_LOG_DIR`.

It would be used as, e.g., follows:

```
* * * * * $CRON_WRAPPER "<job name>" "command"
```

which would record the full output from `stdout` and `stderr` of `command` under:

```
$CRON_LOG_DIR/<date>/<job_name>/command_timestamp.log
```

I am using the script below for `$CRON_WRAPPER`, however, it does not seem to record `stdout` for `command` when command is made of multiple commands, e.g.

```
* * * * * $CRON_WRAPPER "<job name>" "command1 && command2 && command3"
```

Why?

Below is the full `CRON_WRAPPER`

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
COMMAND_NAME=$1
shift

DATE=$(date +%B_%d_%Y)
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)

THIS_CRON_LOG_DIR=$CRON_LOG_DIR/$DATE
mkdir -p $THIS_CRON_LOG_DIR

CRON_LOG_FILE=${THIS_CRON_LOG_DIR}/${COMMAND_NAME}_${TIMESTAMP}.log

# Joining commands:
to_join=$@
joined=$(printf ",%s" "${to_join[@]}")

# Redirecting all output to our logging file:
joined=${joined:1}">> $CRON_LOG_FILE  2>&1"

# Finally evaluating the command
eval $joined
```

Comment: I assume the `&%` is a typo for `&&`?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that @Gilles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first argument to the script is `jobname` and the second is `command1 && command2 && command3` then the command you build up in the `joined` variable is something like

```
command1 && command2 && command3>> /path/to/cron/log/dir/May_12_2015/jobname_2015-05-12_01-09-25.log  2>&1
```

You call `eval` on this string, and it's parsed normally. The redirection only applies to `command3.

You want to treat the second argument as a shell snippet, not as a prefix of a shell snippet. So don't concatenate stuff to it. The redirection belongs directly in the script, not under `eval`, since you're specifying it directly in the script and not via a string that needs to be parsed. Note that your code would break if `jobname` contained any shell special character, e.g. `$CRON_WRAPPER $(touch /tmp/foo) stuff` would execute the code `touch /tmp/foo`.

Another problem with your script is that you're putting commas between the arguments if there are more than two, which doesn't make sense. Joining them with spaces would make more sense, and that's simply `"$*`. (For joining with commas as separators, what you did is overly complex. In zsh, use `${(j:,:)@}`.)

Replace the part of the script starting with `# Joining commands:` by

```
eval "$*" >>$CRON_LOG_FILE  2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't think I was concatenating with a comma!